# How to treat data pasted into Google Sheets as number instead of text and sort accordingly?

Tags: google-sheets

I pasted a table into Google Sheets and one column is

```
1/234
1/102
1/1222
1/83
```

and when sorted according to this column, the column data is treated as "text" and sorted accordingly, meaning 1/102 and 1/1222 both go to the front of the table.  Is it possible to sort them as numbers?

Comment: By numbers do you mean keep them as fractions?

Comment: yes... such as 1/10 = 0.1

Comment: You need to use split to do that. If you want I can get it for you.

Comment: or can you create a new column which is to "parse" the column with 1/102

Comment: It depends on your needs. One way is to use `=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(A2:A7,"/",))` to split and then drag down `=B2/C2`

Answer (score 1):

Add a new column then try formula this :

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(.*)\/")/REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\/(.*)")
```

Or with array formula :

```
=arrayformula(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:a,"(.*)\/")/REGEXEXTRACT(A1:a,"\/(.*)"))
```

Then sort/filter the data with this new column.

---

To revert the process you can try this quick formula to force the custom format :

```
=TEXT(B1,"0/?????")
```

---

Illustration :
[image]